# Parameters in Lie group theory

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

This is from [P.Woit's "Quantum Theory, Groups and Representations"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3319646109), p. 151. If the Hilbert space is the space of complex-valued square-integrable functions on the circle, we want to find the Lie algebra representations corresponding to the "momentum operator" on the circle, i.e. when the representation of the group is

$$
\pi\left(g(\theta)\right)\psi(\phi) = \psi(\phi-\theta).
$$

Now the author says:

> If $X$ is a basis of the Lie algebra $\mathbb{so}(2)$ (for instance, taking the circle as the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$, rotations by 2 by 2 matrices, $X=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $g(\theta)=e^{\theta X}$), then the Lie algebra representation is given by taking the derivative $$\pi'(aX)f(\phi) = \frac{d}{d\theta}f(\phi-a\theta)|_{\theta=0}=-a\frac{d}{d\theta}f(\phi)$$ [...]

Why does the author introduce the $a$ parameter? I'm confused because $\theta$ is simply the action of the group of rotations over the circle, i.e. $\theta \cdot\phi=\phi+\theta$.

(Of course one can make the substitution $X\rightarrow aX$, but my question is really if the $a$ bears a special meaning when he computes $\pi'(aX)$ and not only $\pi'(X)$.)

Comment: This simply gives $a$ times the usual expression for the generator since his action translates by $a\theta$ rather than just $\theta$.  As to why Woit chooses to complicate things (as he often does), you should ask him.  You can always set $a=1$ to recover the more usual formulation.